# How to write a javascript code for calculator with percentage button

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to write a JavaScript code that will input 9% and when the = sign is clicked it will display 0.09

Comment: Please supply an example of what you've tried?

Comment: Please read [ask]: Stackoverflow is not an on-demand  solution-factory. and post So please [edit] the question and post your attempt as [example]! You can use a basic tutorial as start: [How to build a Simple Calculator App with JavaScript](https://freshman.tech/calculator/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code.

```js
function getPercentage(val) {
  return parseFloat(val.substr(0, val.length - 1), 10)/100;
}

console.log(getPercentage('15%'));
```